# Flutter Api Data fetching Error with typeCast and asynchronous suspension

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to fetch the API Data , and it's just returned Circular Progress Indicator when I'm checking my response body from the client Im receiving my required but was unable to display it. Kindly guide me through it where Im going wrong.
My Data from API looks like this
I just want to access **id** and **distance**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "messageId": null,
    "distance": "39",
    "partitionId": "1",
    "eventProcessedUtcTime": "2022-02-08T10:48:12.81",
    "eventEnqueuedUtcTime": "2022-02-08T10:47:38.21",
    "ioThub": "{\"MessageId\":null,\"CorrelationId\":null,\"ConnectionDeviceId\":\"iotwmcs-esp32\",\"ConnectionDeviceGenerationId\":\"637798347400200573\",\"EnqueuedTime\":\"2022-02-08T10:47:38.2060000Z\"}"
  }
]
```

> This is my  file where I'm fetching data

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/models/ilmcs_info.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class UpperLevelTankData extends StatefulWidget {
  const UpperLevelTankData({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _UpperLevelTankDataState createState() => _UpperLevelTankDataState();
}

class _UpperLevelTankDataState extends State<UpperLevelTankData> {
  StreamController<IotWmcsModel> _streamController = StreamController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _streamController.close();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 3), (timer) {
      fetchApiData();
    });
  }

  Future<IotWmcsModel> fetchApiData() async {
    var url = Uri.parse(
        'https://iotwmcsapi20220208180616.azurewebsites.net/api/Iotwmcsta004');
    final response = await http.get(url);
    final dataBody = json.decode(response.body).first;
    // print(dataBody);
    IotWmcsModel iotWmcsModel = IotWmcsModel.fromJson(dataBody);
    _streamController.sink.add(iotWmcsModel);

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<IotWmcsModel>(
      stream: _streamController.stream,
      builder: (context, snapdata) {
        switch (snapdata.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          default:
            if (snapdata.hasError) {
              return const Text('Please Wait....');
            } else {
              return buildIotWmcsWidget(snapdata.data);
            }
        }
      },
    );
  }

  Widget buildIotWmcsWidget(IotWmcsModel iotWmcsModel) {
    print("${iotWmcsModel.distance}");
    return Text(
      "${iotWmcsModel.distance}".toString(),
      style: const TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
    );
  }
}
```

this is  the model of my data

```
class IotWmcsModel {
  final int distance;
  final int id;

  IotWmcsModel({this.distance, this.id});

  factory IotWmcsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return IotWmcsModel(
        distance: json['distance'] as int, id: json['id'] as int);
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'distance': distance,
        'id': id,
      };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Future<List<IotWmcsModel>> fetchApiData() async {
    var url = Uri.parse(
        'https://iotwmcsapi20220208180616.azurewebsites.net/api/Iotwmcsta004');
    final response = await http.get(url);
    List<IotWmcsModel> iotWmcsModel = (response.body as List).map((e) => IotWmcsModel.fromJson(x));

  }
```

coz your api return type is List. And you are trying to fetch as a object, I thing that's the problem

Just try to load as a list then it will work.
N.B: my given code would be bracket problem please make sure that you are fetching request as a List

if you can change the api like below type , then your code will be work

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "messageId": null,
    "distance": "39",
    "partitionId": "1",
    "eventProcessedUtcTime": "2022-02-08T10:48:12.81",
    "eventEnqueuedUtcTime": "2022-02-08T10:47:38.21",
    "ioThub": "{\"MessageId\":null,\"CorrelationId\":null,\"ConnectionDeviceId\":\"iotwmcs-esp32\",\"ConnectionDeviceGenerationId\":\"637798347400200573\",\"EnqueuedTime\":\"2022-02-08T10:47:38.2060000Z\"}"
  }
```

Comment: Your code will be run if you your response start Json Object, if you can change the Aray List to Json object 

{
 "id": 1,
 "messageId": null,
}

Like this way just remove [ ] this from your api

Comment: I have upadted my code  fetching the data from Map, I need another help can you check it please

Comment: Can you Check this  question and reply on it please !  [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71412083/flutter-post-api-with-provider-from-not-working)